# How to detach entity from context when you no longer have a context reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6, datacontext

I am pre-loading product data on my website as I need this to be accessible fast and would rather this be loaded once on application start up rather than just when it's request. This is one way to make sure things load fast. I do this by eager loading my product entity alongside some other entities and store them in memory.

I then have something like the following to retrieve my data:

```
public override IEnumerable<Product> Get()
{
    var result = _cacheManager.Get(PreLoadCacheKey) as IEnumerable<Product>;
    if (result != null)
        return result;

    return base.Get();
}
```

The issue I am facing is that with me using dependency injection, I don't control the scope of my data context (other than setting it to InstancePerRequest() and leaving it be) so when I cache my entities they still have a reference to the original context.

I've tried various things but can't seem to get around the issue of:

```
 The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
```

when trying to attach an entity retrieved from the cache to a new entity I am adding to the database.

Things I've tried:

1. Retrieving the data using `AsNoTracking()`
2. Looping through all the results before adding them to the cache and `Detach`ing them from the current context then attaching them to the new context on retrieval from the cache.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to detach a context from an entity from the side of the entity so I could see if the entity is attached to the current context and if not, detach it from the old one and attach it to the new one. From what I've seen though, the only you can detach it though is by having a reference to the old context which I won't have.

Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit**

This is one example where I'd attach the entity to another context:

```
var orderLine = order.Lines.FirstOrDefault(ol => ol.Product.Id == product.Id) ?? new SalesOrderLine();

orderLine.Price = price.Price;
orderLine.Product = product; //This is my cache'd entity.
orderLine.ProductPriceType = price.ProductPriceType;
orderLine.Quantity += qty;

order.Customer = customer;
order.Lines.Add(orderLine);
order.Status = SalesOrderStatus.Current;

Update(order);
SaveChanges();
```

As it stands at the moment, I am forcibly loading an uncached version to get around this issue.

Comment: Please show the code where this exception is raised. Where do you associate a `Product` to another entity?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the cached data with `AsNoTracking` is the first step. But (apparently) the objects in the cache are created as proxies, so they are aware of having been created by another context.

So make sure that no proxies, but just POCO's are cached, which you do by disabling proxy creation in the context that fetches the objects to the cache:

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

(where `db` is the `DbContext` instance).

Then make sure you attach the object to a new context before you use it there. This is important, because if you `Add()` a new `OrderLine`, EF may try to add a new `Product` as well.

I'd like to add that this would all be so much easier if you'd exposed `OrderLine.ProductId` in your entity model: just setting the Id value would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for this. With regards to your last sentence, in this case it makes perfect sense (and I'll do it) but I have another area which allows editing of the products so I'll get the current product being editing, change the values then call `Update(product)` so this wouldn't help in that case. This proxy thing sounds promising so I'll look at that (strange I've not seen that before).

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't control the life time of your context object i think it would make sense to always detach your product object at the time of loading and attach them when saving the them.

so when you your Get() method is called instead of just checking the cache manger and if not found returning from base.get()  do the following

```
    public override IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        var result = _cacheManager.Get(PreLoadCacheKey) as IEnumerable<Product>;
        if (result != null)
            return result;


        return DetachAndReturn();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> DetachAndReturn()
    {
        foreach (var product in base.Get())
        {
            base.Detach(product);
            yield return product;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. From memory, when I've tried this in the past, attaching the retrieved cache entity to my current context then causes the cached entity to have a reference to my current context which means the next time I retrieve it from the cache, it's again referencing an old context. Does this sound likely? It could be that I misunderstood the issue I faced when trying this before.